# How secure is `apt-get install` when `sudo` access given (via `sudoers` file)

Tags: security, installation, sudo, apt-get

If I have a dozen users on my linux machine (Ubuntu 11.10), what are the security concerns of giving each of them `sudo` access of `apt-get install`.

I want my users to be able to install and use programs without having to send me an e-mail every time. However, can `apt-get` commands ever lead to problems? If so, can some examples be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends in large part on the software repositories that are available to your users.

If you allow your users to add their own repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, then you've given them an unrestricted root account.

If you stick with default Ubuntu repositories with default Ubuntu packages, you're reasonably safe -- at least, I don't know any packages off the top of my head that install blatantly unsafe setuid programs or blatantly unsafe daemons, and I'd expect the Ubuntu security team to take any such bugs seriously.

**Update**

Ubuntu provides [several different kinds of repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu):

```
                    Free software    Almost free software    Proprietary software
Ubuntu Supported       main             restricted
Community Supported    universe                                 multiverse
Vendor Supported                                                  partner
```

Everything in `main` and `restricted` is very-well supported and well-vetted by the Ubuntu security team. `universe` and `multiverse` aren't included on the CDs/DVDs, are supported by the Ubuntu security team in a best-effort sort of way (which in my experience has been quite good, but they aren't about to provide [long-term support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) for any of it).

Everything in `partner` is passed along straight from software vendors without any oversight efforts by Ubuntu security team (though they make lean heavily on vendors of insecure products). Because the vendors want to stay easily available (and on the whole are honest) they won't intentionally do something stupid to compromise your system security.

Since it is [easy to set up your own repository](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository), it's important to ensure that untrusted users cannot add their own repositories to `apt`.

Comment: ya I was thinking more along the lines of Ubuntu defaults. But I don't know much about how apt-get works. From my understanding it installs binaries. But who decides what goes in the list of 'official binaries'? Is there a group of 12 men that meet in secret and come up with this list?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "can the user now run anything they like as root" then the answer is *YES* -- so this is **not safe**.

There are ways that you can run a shell from `dpkg` or `rpm`. For example: `dpkg` will prompt when there is a config file change which clashes, with one of the options being start a shell to examine the situation. **This will start a shell as root if `apt-get` was run via `sudo`**.

Likewise, if you can run an editor from the tool, as most editors let you run arbitrary shell commands from within them (e.g. `!command` in `vi`).

Answer (score 1):

apt-get is usually completely harmless. It is only capable of installing and downloading files.

The worst thing that could happen is that someone would accidentally install a malicious piece of software.

Comment: sarnold addressed my concern, but basically I want to know who has rights to advertise their program? If I created a program where when you downloaded it `sudo apt-get install puk` it essentially issues the command `rm -f - r /`. Can that happen?

Comment: It sure can happen, either in a program that is installed or via a package's post-install scripts. Which is why sticking to well-known popular sources is probably a good idea.